# count the files in directory and loop one by one

Tags: python, count

I have some  different format files in a one directory, but i want to read only .txt file and print the based on the count ,

Example: (one.txt,two.txt,three.txt,four.txt,one.xlsx,two.xlsx)

here i want to count the .txt files and read all .txt file one by one , here the count is 4

read file one.txt

print("hello")

read  file  two.txt

print("hello")

read file  three.txt

print("hello")

read file four.txt

print("hello")

Comment: You can use the *glob* module to easily get filenames based on patterns - e.g., their extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pathlib package from the standard library:

```
from pathlib import Path
myfolder = Path("PATH_TO_YOUR_FOLDER")
txt_files = [p for p in myfolder.iterdir() if p.suffix == ".txt"]
print("Total number of txt files:", len(txt_files)
```